# "Compiler" thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, stack-trace

Sometimes when I get an exception and I check the current threads I see a thread named `"Compiler"` and it's always running `dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)`.

Does anyone have any idea what this thread does or what its purpose is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dalvik is the name for the Android process virtual machine.  So in summary Dalvik is the part of Android that runs your compiled application.  With android 2.2 Dalvik has a Just in time compilation feature so that is probably why you are seeing the 'Compiler'.